# Foundation Zurb DropDown not working with ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I added ng-class to my dropdown menu, to give different classes to the navigation points. Now the subitems don't working anymore, when I hover (just with a click the subitems will open).

```
<section class="top-bar-section para">             
      <ul class="left para">
        <li class="divider2"></li>
        <li ng-class="{'has-dropdown para divider2':navigation.type == 'Sub', 'nav_button divider2':navigation.type == 'Main'}" ng-repeat="navigation in nav.links">

          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Main'" href="{{navigation.link1}}" class="para">{{navigation.name}}</a>
          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" href="#" class="para">{{navigation.name}}</a>
          <ul ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" class="dropdown">              
            <li ng-repeat="subitem in navigation.subitems"><a href="{{subitem.link}}">{{subitem.name2}}</a></li>                
          </ul> 

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

With this Code it is working - But then the navigation point with no submenu has wrong class

```
 <section class="top-bar-section para">             
      <ul class="left para">
        <li class="divider2"></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown divider2" ng-repeat="navigation in nav.links">

          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Main'" href="{{navigation.link1}}" class="para">{{navigation.name}}</a>
          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" href="#" class="para">{{navigation.name}}</a>
          <ul ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" class="dropdown">              
            <li ng-repeat="subitem in navigation.subitems"><a href="{{subitem.link}}">{{subitem.name2}}</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>      -->      
          </ul> 

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

And here my JSON File and Controller.

```
{
"projectTitle": "Test",
"menutitlemobile": "Menu",
"links": [
        {
        "type": "Sub",
        "name": "Menu1",
        "subitems": [{
            "name2": "Sublink1",
            "link": "http://www.google.com"
            }, 
            {
            "name2": "Sublink2",
            "link": "http://www.google.com"
            }]
        },

        {
        "type": "Main",
        "name": "Menu2",
        "link1": "http://www.google.com"
        }

]}
```

---

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'navigation.json',
      data: 'json',
      cache: 'false'       

      }).success(function (data) {              

          $scope.nav = data;
      })

        .error(function(data, status) {

          console.error('Repos error', status, data);
        });});
```

Comment: Hi Sascha, do you have any plunkr (or similar) example?

Comment: Hi...yes here I have one: http://plnkr.co/edit/QH4lhhKjBtekTUkcJ6L2?p=preview

Comment: What Version of Foundation do you use? Is it the complete download?

Comment: Version 5.5.2 - Yes its the complete download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your plunker a bit, have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/CZiKTApTbkc3gnzy5eMl?p=preview

Be sure to load AngularJS only once and jQuery to be loaded before AngularJS (`index.html`).

In `app.js` I added a `$timeout` after your data is loaded. With this "out of scope" action it seams to work.

Not nice, but it works ;)